# Hiding background images on smaller screens

Tags: css

I have some big background photos that I don't want to display in smaller screens, mobile etc. And i want to display the colour defined as background color.

The code is

```
#search_container1 {
position: relative;
height: 500px;
background: #4d536d url(../img/slide_hero.jpg) no-repeat center top;
background-size: cover;
color:#fff;
width: 100%;
display:table;
z-index:99;
```

I have tried

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
#search_container1 {
        background-image: none !important;

    }
}
```

but didnt work.

How can be the easy way?

Comment: `#search_container1` is not the same as `#search`.  Could this be a typo?  Also, I thought it was recommended to use `min-width` media queries when trying to not load in large images, because otherwise the image still loads.  Although, maybe that's not true anymore anyway.

Comment: @JosephMarikle yeah what they have works fine if they fix the selector https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWpjrE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first rule, you used `background` , not `background-image`, but you have to overwrite it with the same parameter.

So your media query has to use the `background` parameter, too, just without the image:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #search_container1 {
        background: #4d536d !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure? this seems to work fine. copied and pasted. they just have a typo in the selector https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWpjrE

Comment: @MichaelCoker It might depend on the browser, but this is my experience...

Comment: Dear Michael, thanks but if i use like that. Removes all teh background images.

Comment: This is not correct.  `background` is just the shorthand.  `background-image` applied in a media query that cascades after the initial rule will only override the `background-image` part of the rule.

Comment: @lospicos "all the background images" - what do you mean? Do you mean it removes the background image and the background color? Does this happen in a particular browser?

Comment: @MichaelCoker I have background image also on the footer. So need to use for a special class.

Comment: @lospicos how is that relevant to your post? Include all of the code that's relevant to the problem. We can't guess at what other elements are on your page. Also, you're referencing ID's, so the CSS here should only affect 1 element - not multiple ones.

Comment: @MichaelCoker as it was really big page I didint put here. Yes that is an id. id="search_container1"

Comment: @lospicos if it's relevant to your solution, you need to include it in the post. You don't have to include the whole thing - just everything that gives context to the problem in your OP. But that said, re-defining as `background: #4d536d;` is the same thing as `background: #4d536d url(../img/slide_hero.jpg) no-repeat center top; background-image: none;` visually except the solution in this answer will also unset your `background-position` and `background-repeat` properties for any other elements that were using the original `background` property with the image.